# Display icon next to input field

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so that the `label` is directly on top of an `input` field, and I want an icon to display right *next* to said `input` field.

```css
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");

input,
label {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" placeholder="Username" class="">
    <i class="material-icons">accessibility</i>
</div>
```

I can get the `label` above the `input` using the above CSS.
But how do I get the `icon` next to the input field?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51zrg6ms/)

Comment: Do You need it just after the input field ??

Comment: Yes, so the icon should be to the *right* of the input field (not below, as it is in the jsfiddle).

Comment: The simplest change is just to remove _input_ from your CSS rule: `input, label {
    display: block;
}` becomes `label {
    display: block;
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");

label {
  display: block;
}

input{
  display:inline;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input id="username"
         placeholder="Username"
         class="">
  <i class="material-icons">accessibility</i>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't even need the `input { display: inline; }` since inline is the default for an `<input>`

Answer (score 1):

The input must be displayed as an inline-block

```
 label {
   display: block;
 }

 input {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/51zrg6ms/2/

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be `inline-block` — `inline` works fine and is the default display property for an `input` element.

Comment: Yes you can; but personally I Prefer inline-block if you like to add some margins and paddings later for more perfect positioning.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming across this post in a search, there is a thread on the MaterializeCSS repo on various ways to implement this. See: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1214

I'm using the solution posted by amikeret in this reply: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1214#issuecomment-430598527

His code is

```
.input-field {
  // Add inset definition to .prefix
  .prefix {
    &:not(.inset) {
      & ~ input,
      & ~ textarea,
      & ~ label,
      & ~ .validate ~ label,
      & ~ .helper-text,
      & ~ .autocomplete-content {
        margin-left: 3rem;
      }
    }
    &.inset {
      & ~ input,
      & ~ textarea,
      & ~ label,
      & ~ .validate ~ label,
      & ~ .helper-text,
      & ~ .autocomplete-content {
        margin-left: 0;   // This is a patch until it's incorporated into the framework
        padding-left: 3rem;
      }
    }
  }

  // Suffix Icons
  .suffix {
    position: absolute;
    width: $input-height;
    font-size: $input-icon-size;
    transition: color .2s;
    top: ($input-height - $input-icon-size) / 2;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;

    &.active { color: $input-focus-color; }
  }
  .suffix {
    & ~ input,
    & ~ textarea,
    & ~ label,
    & ~ .validate ~ label,
    & ~ .helper-text,
    & ~ .autocomplete-content {
      width: calc(100% - 3rem);
    }
    &:not(.inset) {
      & ~ input,
      & ~ textarea,
      & ~ label,
      & ~ .validate ~ label,
      & ~ .helper-text,
      & ~ .autocomplete-content {
        margin-right: 3rem;
      }
    }
    &.inset {
      & ~ input,
      & ~ textarea,
      & ~ label,
      & ~ .validate ~ label,
      & ~ .helper-text,
      & ~ .autocomplete-content {
        padding-right: 3rem;
      }
    }
  }
  .suffix ~ label { margin-right: 3rem; }
  &.col {
    .suffix ~ label,
    .suffix ~ .validate ~ label {
      width: calc(100% - 3rem - #{$gutter-width});
    }
  }

  // What if we have both prefix and suffix?
  .prefix ~ .suffix ~ input {
    width: calc(100% - 6em);
  }
  &.col {
    .suffix ~ .suffix ~ label,
    .suffix ~ .suffix ~ .validate ~ label {
      width: calc(100% - 6rem - #{$gutter-width});
    }
  }
}

// Inset icons
.material-icons {
  &.inset {
    font-size: $input-icon-size * .75;
    top: ($input-height - $input-icon-size) / 2 * 1.5;
  }
  &.actionable {
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```